# Show 0 if null in query

Tags: sql-server

I am running a sql query that is omitting the day if the return count is 0.  I want my query to return the day and a 0 count if the the count is 0.  Snare I have is that if 0 were sold for the day, the day is omitted from my return results.

```
SELECT ISNULL([day],0) As [day], COUNT(ISNULL(Sold,0)) As [Sold]
FROM productionInfo
```

Comment: use COALESCE instead of ISNULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're drawing information from a single table, `productionInfo`. If `productionInfo` has no rows with that date information (because there are no widgets sold on that date), how does it know what dates to use?

You might want to look at using a [Numbers Table](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=NumbersTable) to get a row for each day of the month/year, then join that to `productionInfo` so you have a day value available, even if there was no production that day.

Comment: It would be ideal if I do not have to create a different table.  Could I somehow specify this info in my where clause?

Comment: WHERE clauses can only draw on existing information - if the date information isn't in the table, it needs to come from somewhere.

If you're doing this as part of a reporting function, you could try using an @table variable in the function and populating it with the values 1-31 or 1-366.

Comment: I created a table to house the acceptable values - now how do I tie that into my query so all results in the table are displayed with a count?

Comment: (acceptable values table) LEFT OUTER JOIN (productionInfo) on (whatever day-value link you have) should do the trick. Then just use the COUNT aggregate like you were originally.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a dates table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DatesTable (@startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME) 
RETURNS @retTable TABLE (DateValue DATETIME)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @currentDate DATETIME

    SET @currentDate = @startDate


    WHILE (DATEDIFF(dd, @currentDate, @endDate) >= 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @retTable VALUES (@currentDate)

        SET @currentDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, @currentDate)
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Then your query will look like:

```
SELECT dt.DateValue AS [day], COUNT(Sold) AS [Sold] 
FROM dbo.DatesTable('2-1-2014', '2-10-2014') dt
    LEFT JOIN productionInfo pi ON pi.day = dt.DateValue
GROUP BY dt.DateValue
```